# Setting shipping method in the order creation process

Tags: magento-1, shipping-methods

I want to set a shipping method in order to create an order, but i got the following message error: "Please specify a shipping method". This is my code:
First try:

```
$shippingAddress->setFreeShipping( true )
            ->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
            ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping')
            ->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery');
```

Second try:

```
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod('freeshipping');
```

None of these are not working. Any idea how to solve this is welcomed. Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `freeshipping` method is active and its rate exists in the `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Address_Rate_Collection` collection.

EDIT: Don't forget to check if the address you're setting the shipping method against is eventually saved.